# Issues with writing to dynamically named MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create dynamically named MySQL tables in routines using a prefix based on a model run number which I set in php as the `@ModelRef` variable.

I can usually create the tables no problem but sometimes the routine crashes when trying to write data to the newly created table.  The following code works:

```
SET @TableName = CONCAT('`',@ModelRef, '_', 'input_actual_php','`');

SET @Table_Text:=CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ',@TableName, ' (
    case_id                 INT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 1,
    Savings1                DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    Savings2                DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    TermDeposit             DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    FC_Dist                 INT DEFAULT NULL)'

    );

    PREPARE stmt from @Table_Text;
    EXECUTE stmt;   

-- Write values to table
    SET @TableEdit:=CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@TableName,' VALUES
        (case_id, @Savings1, @Savings2, @TermDeposit, @FC_Dist)');

    PREPARE stmt from @TableEdit;
    EXECUTE stmt;
```

and yet the following code in a different routine does not:

```
SET @TableName_1 = CONCAT('`', @ModelRef, '_lookup_wage_growth','`');

SET @Table_Text_1:=CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ',@TableName_1, ' (
    Age INT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0,
    ModYear INT DEFAULT 0,
    Growth_1 DECIMAL(5 , 3 ) DEFAULT 0,
    GrowthInd_1 DECIMAL(5 , 3 ) DEFAULT 0,
    NomWage_1 INT DEFAULT 0,
    NomWage_1_UD INT DEFAULT 0)'
);

PREPARE stmt from @Table_Text_1;
EXECUTE stmt; 

-- Code here doing calculations and generating values

-- Write to table
        SET @TableEdit_1:=CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@TableName_1,' VALUES
            (age_var, ModYear_var, Growth_1_var, GrowthInd_1_var, NomWage_1_var, @NomWage_1_UD)'); 

        PREPARE stmt from @TableEdit_1;
        EXECUTE stmt;
```

I have tried and played with different variations of above and simplified everything and yet I can't work out why the second routine fails to write to the table and crash.  Is there something I am missing??

Comment: have you checked your logs?

Comment: Dynamically creating tables is probably a bad plan, it's against proper relational design principles. What about using a singular table with a column for segmentation and/or partitioning?

Comment: Hi @Funk Forty Niner, no I did not have them enabled.  I now know I need to enable logs in this location /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf - but a stupid question - where is this?  I found /etc/ under the windows drivers directory - no relevant file there??  I am running WAMP locally

Comment: Look and do a search for *.cnf or .log under your c:\wamp\ folder, if that's the default folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend against this pattern altogether. What is wrong with having one table with a "modelRef" field?

But if you need to/must proceed with it in this manner for some reason; it looks like you are inserting `age_var` into `Age`, and `age_var` is not defined anywhere, and I am not sure if it would even be accessible as from a PREPAREd statement unless it it were a user/session/@ variable.

Assuming it was DECLAREd in "doing calculations and generating values"; you'd need

```
SET @TableEdit_1:=CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@TableName_1,' 
                          VALUES (', age_var, ', ', ModYear_var, ', ' ....
```

*Also, I tend to err on the side of caution and postfix most @-variable identifiers in stored procedures with a guid I generate for that procedure. You can end up with difficult to track bugs using what are effectively global variables (for the connection).*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the comments and recommendations provided.  I have taken these on board and changed my approach.

Rather than create and write to dynamically labelled tables, I have changed their creation from `CREATE TABLE` to `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` and this has removed the conflict created between users manipulating tables with common names.  The temporary tables last as long as the connection to the database exists and are created for each user and dropped immediately afterwards, long enough for routine calculation and extraction of data to client side.